# query in MYSQL to show available balance + 5% in certain accounts

Tags: mysql

I need help on this--tried all day yesterday to get it to work  to no avail. I need to write a query that will show the available balance of certain accounts if 5% were added.

```
Update account
 set avail_balance = avail_balance*1.05
 where product_cd = 'CD';
Select avail_balance, product_cd
from account;
```

I got the available balances, but it displayed it for all accounts, not just those with the product_cd of 'CD.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You mean "Select avail_balance, product_cd from account where product_cd = 'CD';"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an "UPDATE", you are actaully UPDATING the balance... To get a result IF 5% WAS ADDED, you should only have to

```
select a.AccountNumber,
      a.AnyOtherColumnsYouWantToShow,
      a.Avail_Balance * 1.05 as AvailPlus5Percent
   from
      Account a
   where
      a.Product_CD = 'CD';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),a.Avail_Balance) * 1.05 as ConvertedValue
   FROM
      Account
   WHERE
      Product_CD = 'CD'

You dont have to convert it to decimal. Howeverm you question is a bit unclear. Do you want to select or update?